# iOS 8.1 Fullscreen Safari iPod Touch 5th generation

Tags: ios, html, fullscreen

I have 3 html pages. I want to open this pages with my iPod Touch in fullscreen mode. These 3 pages are connected to each other. Here is a little example:

[image]

Every `.html` page contains this code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Language" content="en" >
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" >
  
  <meta name="apple-touch-fullscreen" content="yes" />
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black">
 
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
 </head>
 <body>
  <!--
          ...
        -->
 </body>
</html>
```

I followed the steps [on this page here](http://www.fischlexikon.eu/service/mobile-app.php) (look at the images (Point: iPhone (IOS))) to make a "`web-app`" in fullscreen mode. Now i made the `index.html` as "`web-app`" on the homescreen. When I press the icon, I see the `index.html` in fullscreen mode.

Now I want to press a button and get the next page in fullscreen too, butat the moment the next page will shown in the normal safari browser without the fullscreen mode. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Are all the pages on the same domain? Are any of them in your cache manifest? What do your links look like (HTML code)? It would be useful if you shared a minimal example showing the problem.

Comment: @jcaron the wesite isn't online. What do you mean with the cache manifest? The links looks like this: `<a id="btnMoveUp" unselectable="on" class="operationButton">Button</a>`. Thats nearly all on the page. Much javascript, but I think thats not the problem, because I use the js to communicate with `PLC`. I have some `<div></div>` containers on the page, but they are useless too.

Comment: Those are not standard HTML links, so it really depends what the Javascript you have does with them so they are actually links. Have you tried with regular (`<a href="...">`) links to see what happens in this case?

Comment: @jcaron sorry, I posted the wrong button... The Buttons looks like : `<a id="btnBack" unselectable="on" class="operationButton" href="index.html">Back</a>`

Comment: Try to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and post it online so other users can test it.